# SVN externals repo "is already locked" on update

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svn-externals

Basically I have to repo on the same server:

```
svn://repo/foo
-> checked out to d:\foo

svn://repo/bar
-> d:\foo has an svn:external property set to check this out into d:\foo\bar
```

When an "svn:update" or a new "svn:checkout" this is gist of the error:

```
Command - Update
Updated - D:\foo
External - D:\foo\bar
External failed - D:\foo\bar
Error - d:\foo\bar is already locked via d:\foo
```

After I "clean" or manually release the lock, the problem still persists.

Any insights would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**Update:**

Attila nailed it in the comment. I had "foo/bar" existing in the repository.

For future reference - when using SVN:External property, SVN **will create** the destination folder for the external reference.

Comment: Do you have an svn://repo/foo/bar folder in the repository?  That could cause problems when you are trying to check out the external to the same directory (d:\foo\bar)

Comment: Actually Attila that is exactly what happened.  I expected that the folder would have to exist.  Turns out "svn:externals" property will create the destination folder if it doesn't exist.

Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 13):

As resolved in the comments (just to have it in proper answer as well):

When using svn:externals, the directory where the externals repository is checked out should not exist in the original repository

Comment: Just to add another case where this comes up...  I had a directory `myLib` within a repo.  The repo had externals `myLib/partA` and `myLib/partB`.  I wanted instead to have `myLib` external directly to the parent of `partA` and `partB` within my external library.  Before I could do this I not only had to `svn delete` the `myLib` directory, but also commit that change otherwise `myLib` kept getting recreated even if I 'regular' deleted it.

Comment: This is confusing, can you elaborate on this and maybe provide a screenshot/directory structure to show an example? I'm getting this error and not sure which directory I should be removing...